why does the File widget not work on flutter web using imagepicker
I have so many issues in flutter firebase web . I am using the File widget in flutter and it is working perfectly on flutter firebase iOS and android but not on the web. please what should i do to resolve this issue. Here is my code i would appreciate a quick reply as i am working on a project and it has a deadline.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/T9G0Q.png)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Also please include what you are expecting to get (what you get on mobile) versus what you are currently getting, any errors, blank screen, etc.
